# jni return string array from c / c++11 and use on java without for loop on c++ side?

Tags: java, c, c++11, java-native-interface, jnienv

why make a foor loop once on jni side  and one more on java side ?
i'ts possible to return just the array without for loop ?

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_main_returndays(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{

  char *days[]={"Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"};

  jstring str;
  jobjectArray day = 0;
  jsize len = 7;
  int i;

  day = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,len,(*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/String"),0);

  for(i=0;i<7;i++)//// without this loop ?
  {
    str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,days[i]);
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,day,i,str);
  }

return day;
}
```

Comment: Have  you tried using `while?`

Comment: for loop or while  loop it's the same thing , just diffrent condition

Answer (score 1):

In order to return a String[] to Java via JNI, you must create the array and then convert and set each string into the array.  There isn't any shortcut like passing the char** back to Java.

However... if your goal is to avoid creating Java Strings in C++ via JNI, and do it in Java instead, you can accomplish this.  There are sometimes good reasons for doing so.  In our software, we hand complex data structures from C++ to Java.  We've found that using JNI to build the data structures is very slow (JNI method calls are like 1000 clock cycles each).  It is often faster to serialize to a byte array in C++, create a single JNI byte array, hand it across the JNI boundary to Java, and have the Java deserialize the byte array.

I'm not going to give you a complete, working example, but it goes something like this.  I'm going to build a byte array in C++ that has nulls between each string, then hand it to Java for process into a List (easier than String[]).

C++:

```
// Find overall length with nulls
int len = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(days)/sizeof(char*); i++) {
   len += strlen(days[i]) + 1;
}
// Fill C++ byte array
char* cBytes = new char[len];
char* ptr = cBytes;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(days)/sizeof(char*); i++) {
   strcpy(ptr, days[i]); 
   ptr += strlen(days[i]) + 1;
}
// Copy C++ to Java
jbyteArray jBytes = env->NewByteArray(len);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(jBytes, 0, len, cBytes);
delete [] cBytes;
return jBytes;
```

Java:

```
byte jBytes[] = // call C++ via JNI
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
int offset = 0;
// break byte array at null, convert to String
while (offset < jBytes.length) {
   for (int i = offset; true; i++) {
      if (jBytes[i] == 0) {
         // Default code page assumed.  You could also pass a Charset.
         strs.add(new String(jBytes, offset, i - offset));
         offset = i + 1;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

I realize that there are "even more optimal" ways of passing arrays between C++ and Java, usually involving some sort of NativeByteBuffer wrapper.  But these methods often have special cases and are more complex.